# References error in Visual Studio 2015 RC in ASP.NET 5 Web Application

Tags: asp.net-core, visual-studio-2015, asp.net-core-mvc

I have an ASP.NET 5 MVC Application, and can't restore references because I get on solution explorer "References (Errors - see error list)", on the error list I have:

> The specified path, file name, or both are too long. The fully qualified file name must be less than 260 characters, and the directory name must be less than 248 characters.

I moved the project even to the root folder to shorten the path - but without results, The error appears after I restore the NPM packages, that are the packages that I user:

```
  "devDependencies": {
"grunt": "0.4.5",
"grunt-contrib-uglify": "0.8.0",
"grunt-contrib-watch": "0.6.1",
"grunt-bower-task": "0.4.0",
"grunt-contrib-less": "1.0.1",
"less-plugin-autoprefix": "1.4.1"
 },
 "dependencies": {
     "grunt-contrib-uglify": "^0.8.0"
 }
```

After removing one by one NPM packages, I found that this guy is guilty:

```
 "grunt-bower-task": "0.4.0"
```

I guess, some bower package has a really long file name, will investigate it further by removing bower packages one by one (I have plenty of them in my app). But if somebody has a better way, please help.

Removing bower packages (even all of them didn't help) so it looks like it's an issue with grunt-bower-task npm package.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Adding to project.json:

```
 "exclude": [
    "wwwroot",
    "node_modules",
    "bower_components"
]
```

solved the problem (I didn't had this because the project.json was created in an early beta release of VS2015)

Answer (score 0):

Remove complaining folder in `[PROJECT]/node_modules/grunt-bower-task/[complaining]` and retry

Comment: but what is a complaining folder?

Comment: you should have them in the exception details `The specified path, file name, or both are too long`

Comment: I don't have any exception details